# ngSwitch is "Attribute Directive" OR "Structural Directive" ?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular2-directives, ng-switch

I am a bit confused regarding ngSwitch directive -- whether it is **'attribute directive'** or **'structural directive'**.

Attribute directives are written with '**square brackets**' like [ngStyle], [ngClass], etc. (and we write it as [ngSwitch] which refers it as 'Attribute Directives').

Structural directives are written with '**aestrick**' like *ngFor, *ngIf, etc. (and we write the cases as *ngSwitchCase="..." which means it is a structural directive).

```
<div [ngSwitch]="colorValue">
    <p *ngSwitchCase="red">Red</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="blue">Blue</p>
    <p *ngSwitchCase="green">Green</p>
</div>
```

As per the code above, it is getting very confusing to categorize ngSwtich to either of the Directive Categories! Can someone help me out in understanding the directive-type of ngSwitch ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[ngSwitch]` is an **attribute directive** used in combination with `*ngSwitchCase` and `*ngSwitchDefault` that are both **structural directives**.

This is clearly explained in Angular's documentation...

> - `NgSwitch` — an **attribute directive** that changes the behavior of its companion directives.
> - `NgSwitchCase` — **structural directive** that adds its element to the DOM when its bound value equals the switch value and removes its bound value when it doesn't equal the switch value.
> - `NgSwitchDefault` — **structural directive** that adds its element to the DOM when there is no selected NgSwitchCase.

https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#switching-cases-with-ngswitch

Comment: And yet in the same [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#built-in-structural-directives) : *"This section is an introduction to the common structural directives: NgIf, NgSwitch, NgForOf"*?, maybe it would've been better to quote *"NgSwitch itself is not a structural directive. It's an attribute directive that controls the behavior of the other two switch directives. That's why you write [ngSwitch], never *ngSwitch...."* from [here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngswitch-directives)

Comment: Link probably out of date.. try: https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Comment: @KieranRyan Thank you, I updated the outdated link to the new related section of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

Structural directives  updates the DOM layout by adding or removing elements.

Comment: [*"NgSwitch itself is not a structural directive"*](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngswitch-directives)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.0.2/packages/common/src/directives/ng_switch.ts#L35-L127

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it , **'structural directive'** change the dom's struct. **attribute directive** change the dom's attribute,such as color,background and so on

**ngSwitch** change it's children's length , so its a **structural directive**,

Answer (score 0):

**Structural Directive:**

**What are structural directives?**

Structural directives are responsible for HTML layout. They shape or reshape the DOM's structure, typically by adding, removing, or manipulating elements.

As with other directives, you apply a structural directive to a host element. The directive then does whatever it's supposed to do with that host element and its descendants.

Structural directives are easy to recognize. An asterisk (*) precedes the directive attribute name as in this example.

Refer: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Answer (score 0):

ngSwitch is a built-in structural directive. 
[https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives]

@j3ff: The (*) star on *ngSwitchCase is merely sugar syntax, 
it does not indicate the type of directive.

It could be written the long way like this...

```
<div class="course-category" [ngSwitch]="colorValue">
 <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="'RED'">
  <div>
   <p>Red</p>
  </div>
 </ng-template>
```

Comment: I thought i read somewhere else, * represent structure directive.  ngClass and ngStyle are attribute directive, and it does not have * in front

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be a bit confusing for beginners but still it is not that much difficult to understand. Let me explain clearly.

**ngSwitch** directive is a unique one which is classified as a **structural** directive because it can alter (add or remove) elements based from the DOM based on the condition.

Though it is an structural directive, the syntax for ngSwitch comprises both attribute-like and structural-like parts.

The difference arises because the **ngSwitch** is used as **attribute** directive and the **ngSwitchCase** is used as **structural directive**.

But both of them are classified as structural directive because they both are participating in building of conditional blocks.